# How to get text change value of label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<p class="postal">
  <label contenteditable="true" class="tabValue">post code</label>
  <label contenteditable="true" class="tabValue">post code</label>
</p>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.tabValue').change(function() {
    console.log(this.innerText);
   });
});
```

I have been trying with this core but not able to take the change text value to console.
Please visit this link for sample: http://jsfiddle.net/wqje0x6s/2/

Comment: Use `$(this).text()`

Comment: I dont know much about keyup

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
value = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text()` in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabValue').focusout(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqje0x6s/4/)

Answer (score 0):

how do you plan to "change" you label? Maybe you want to use click?

```
$('.tabValue').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem with this approach is that I want to change the new value of the label to database. And if I use click, it will always hit the database whenever the label is clicked. So I am looking for a approach where it hits the database only when the value of the label changes.

Comment: well, to change label text - you need something that will init this change, any element action. You do not have such action in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `input/blur` events; `change` event does not fire on `contenteditable` elements

```
$('.tabValue').on('blur input',function() {
    console.log(this.innerText);
});
```

```js
var currVal = {};
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tabValue').on('blur', function () {
        if(currVal[this] === this.innerText){
            //Do not call DB        
        }
        else{
            currVal[this] = this.innerText;
            console.log(this.innerText);
            //Call DB
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="postal">
  <label contenteditable="true" class="tabValue">post code</label>
  <label contenteditable="true" class="tabValue">post code</label>
</p>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st78djn0/3/)

> Note : `input` might not work on old browsers. Use `blur/focusout` then

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem with this approach is that I want to change the new value of the label to database. And if I use blur, it will always hit the database whenever the lable is out of focus.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am  showing on click of label changing text and  its working for me

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#tabValue').click(function() {
        $("#tabValue").text('Text changed');
    });
})
```